# Visual Studio Database Project + Deploy + TFS Build + Multi Tenancy

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, tfs, database-project

We have recently migrated to using the Visual Studio database projects. What we want to do is for the database to deploy when the TFS build server builds.

This is relatively simple and we have this working for a single database, however, what we need is for it to deploy to multiple database as we have a SaaS product with multiple databases. So for example, when we do a QA build, all the different databases with various configurations on the QA DB server should be updated.

Is there a 'proper' way to do this?

Our current plan is to take the deployment .sql script that will be generated from the database configured for deployment, then create a custom build task which runs this script against the rest of the databases.

Comment: Out of interest, are you using VS2010 database projects or the SSDT database projects? Here at Red Gate we're moving towards supporting the latter for continuous integration and deployment, but it is unlikely that the older database projects will be in scope.

Comment: Ah.. shame. Any near-term plans to upgrade?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson I'm not too sure what SSDT is; why would the OP (David Masters) benefit from using that instead of the default Database templates provided by VS2010 eg "SQL Server 2008 Database Project", or "SQL Server 2008 Server Project"

Comment: With SSDT they mean this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx which can also be used for VS 2010. Deployment can then be done with the MSBuild task that ships with the SSDT tooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way of doing this, so we created a custom build task that iterates over the databases we want to deploy to executing the deployment script generated by the standard database project's deploy against each DB.